# "chunk is too big to transmit" Android logcat Meaning?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm getting this warning in my logcat while running an app with Google Maps:

`chunk is too big to transmit (length=49398928, 48259 bytes)`

I think it has something to do with memory fragmentation, but I was hoping someone could confirm, provide an explanation and/or resolution? It starts occurring before an out of memory error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MapFragment Google Maps API v2 Out of Memory Error / Memory Leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533347/mapfragment-google-maps-api-v2-out-of-memory-error-memory-leak)